# how to fill the hook using foreach

Tags: react-native, foreach, react-hooks

I need to fill hook using foreach statement. Using my code I can only assign the last value from Data object. Please help me to create right approach to fill the hook using 'value' from Data. I need Percent={123,456,789} instead {789} only.

```
<pre><code>
function App() {
  const [Percentage, SetPercentage]=useState([]);
  const Data=[
    {sensor: 'abcd', value: 123},
    {sensor: 'efgh', value: 456},
    {sensor: 'ijkl', value: 789}
  ]
  const Show=()=>
  {
      Data.forEach((key)=>{
      SetPercentage([...Percentage,key.value]);
    })}
  return (
    &lt;View style={styles.app}>
      <Button onPress={Show} title='Show'></Button>
      {Percentage.map(()=>{
        return(
             &lt;View>
             &lt;Text>map={Percentage}&lt;/Text> 
          &lt;/View>
      )})}
    &lt;/View>
  );
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Do you want to display the list of values from the data object?

Comment: Yes, but I need to recalculate these values, so I need to store it in the hook

Comment: Sorry for wrong tags. This my very first post in terms of the frontend

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using map approach

```
SetPercentage(data.map(entry=>entry.value))
```

This will fill the percentage with 123,456,789

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get incorrect results and performance issues by updating state in loops like:

```
  const Show=()=>
  {
      Data.forEach((key)=>{
      SetPercentage([...Percentage,key.value]); 
    })}
```

Avoid mutation like this and rather build up your value and set the state once:

```
const show = () => {
    const vals = data.map((item) => item.value);
    setPercentage(vals); 

    // or
    setPercentage(data.map((item) => item.value));
  };
```

While you are simply showing a demo, it would be best to move `data` outside the component and also ensure you have a [unique key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in your map--ideally not the index iterator and rather something unique.

```
const data = [
  { sensor: "abcd", value: 123 },
  { sensor: "efgh", value: 456 },
  { sensor: "ijkl", value: 789 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState<Array<number>>([]);

  const show = () => {
    // set state once
    const vals = data.map((item) => item.value);
    setPercentage(vals);

    // or
    setPercentage(data.map((item) => item.value));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={show}>Show</button>
      {percentage &&
        percentage.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item}</div>)}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-einstein-kzxbj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I'll try to use it :)